# Unable to Use repeater item on Item bound function

Tags: asp.net, linq, webforms

MY code throw exception on repeater itemDataBound

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType4`18[System.String,System.Int64,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Decimal,System.Int32,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Decimal,System.String,System.Boolean]'
>   to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

```
  public void GetUploadFIlesDetils_Level2() 
    {
       var result2 = from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          where t.Field<string>("PracticeName") == practiceName  && t.Field<string>("Provider") == Provider
                          select new
                          {  
                              PracticeName = t.Field<string>("PracticeName"),
                              FileId = t.Field<long>("UploadFIlesID"),
                              FileName = t.Field<string>("FileName")
    }

    rptlevel2.DataSource = result2;
        rptlevel2.DataBind();

    }
```

My ItemDataBound function is:

```
  protected void rptlevel2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {

          if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using anonymous type to project into `DataRowView`, better to create a model class which all of its properties have the same naming as projected properties instead:

```
public class Practice
{
    public string PracticeName { get; set; }
    public long FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify the query to contain the model class:

```
var result2 = from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where t.Field<string>("PracticeName") == practiceName  && t.Field<string>("Provider") == Provider
              select new Practice // add the model class name here
              {  
                   PracticeName = t.Field<string>("PracticeName"),
                   FileId = t.Field<long>("UploadFIlesID"),
                   FileName = t.Field<string>("FileName")
              };
```

Finally, use the model class name as mentioned above to cast from `DataItem` object to get corresponding row instance:

```
Practice practice = (Practice)e.Item.DataItem;
```